# i am new in c#. I need to know which is the reference to be add when i need to loop controls (textbox)

Tags: c#

```
foreach (Textbox tb in this.Controls)
        {
            if (tb != null)
            {
            }
        }
```

I need to do this but the reference is missing. I dont´t know which is. Please can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Well what exact error message are you facing? What `using` directives do you already have? What makes you think it's to do with looping?

Comment: No se puede encontrar el tipo o el nombre de espacio de nombres 'Textbox' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?). I have: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

Comment: So please put that into the question, ideally with a translation into English - or temporarily set your machine into English so you can get the English message.

Comment: It would also have helped if you'd said this was a WebForms project to start with, rather than WinForms. What's the type of `this`? `Page`? (Also note that this code will throw an exception if `Controls` has any control that *isn't* a `TextBox` in - that's probably not what you want.)

Comment: Finally, which `TextBox` class do you think you're trying to refer to?

Comment: I really appreciate your help!! It's my first time in this forum and I'm learning how to interact. I will improve the way I ask the questions. the error in english is "The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" It is a WebForms project. What I need to do is a loop of all texbox controls of the page and add the value of each textbox to a GridView.I need to generate a procedure to use it on all pages. The code I used, I got it from a forum and it probably is not correct. Many thanks

Comment: I suspect you got that code from an answer about WinForms. Again, what exact type did you expect? What type are you using in your form?

Answer (score 2):

If this is a windows forms application, add `using System.Windows.Forms`.

When you don't know what reference is missing you can press CTRL + . on the highlighted line to automatically include the reference. Keep in mind that this requires the library to be included in your Project References. If it's not than you should add it there first.

Comment: Hey that's a great tip(the  CTRL +), I am adding that shortcut to my fav list!  Thanks @deadzone